# Enable/Disable Advertiser Tracking for Meta in ionic capacitor application?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, capacitor, facebook-ads-api

I was trying to enable Advertiser Tracking using capacitor-community
facebook-login plugin.i found a method for enabling ( i guess ) in  documentation of [facebook-login plugin](https://github.com/capacitor-community/facebook-login/tree/master?tab=readme-ov-file#facebookconfiguration) but there is no documentation for how to use it and demo project given also not mentioning about apis present in given plugin.

method defined in documentation:

```
setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(...)
```

but when I try to use it I am getting the error

> property 'setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled' does not exist on type 'FacebookLoginPlugin'.ts(2339)

my code so far

```
async enableAdvertiserTracking(){
    await FacebookLogin.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled({ enabled: true; })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is available in latest version ( starting from 5.0.0 ) of [@capacitor-community/facebook-login](https://github.com/capacitor-community/facebook-login/tree/master?tab=readme-ov-file#setadvertisertrackingenabled).

may be you are using older version of the same plugin.you should call this method after requesting tracking permission from user in ios.

for that purpose you can use [capacitor-plugin-app-tracking-transparency](https://www.npmjs.com/package/capacitor-plugin-app-tracking-transparency).as mentioned below

```
let response = await AppTrackingTransparency.getStatus();
if (response.status === 'notDetermined') {
  // Ask user consent to track
  response = await AppTrackingTransparency.requestPermission();
}

// set based on user consent

if(response.status === 'authorized'){
  await FacebookLogin.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled({ enabled: true; })
} else {
  await FacebookLogin.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled({ enabled: false; })
}
```

if you are using capacitor version below 5 you won't be able to use `setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled` from @cacpacitor-community/facebook-login.

if your are on capacitor 4 or less you can use [@captive/capacitor-facebook-analytics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@captive/capacitor-facebook-analytics) version 1.0.0 to acheive same.in that case you have to change last few lines as below

```
if(response.status === 'authorized'){
  FacebookAnalytics.enableAdvertiserTracking()
} else {
  FacebookAnalytics.disableAdvertiserTracking()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use cordova facebook-connect plugin although it bit old.it has a method to enable advertiser tracking.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-facebook-connect#facebook-sdk

Comment: we had migrated from above plugin capacitor-community/facebook-login because it was using graph api version 11.0 ( which has expired last september ). is there any other way to acheive the same without migrating back to facebook-connect. or adding an additional dependency

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57934557/how-to-set-facebookautologappeventsenabled-to-true-in-a-cordova-ios-project-usin